# Can you use the Grails Wrapper to upgrade Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.1, grails-2.2

I can't find anything in the Grails docs, but [from the wording of the description of the Grails Wrapper](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#wrapper), it should be possible.

Can you use Grails (via an installed Grails Wrapper) to upgrade the version of Grails a project (and thus the Wrapper) is using? If so, how?

TIA,
g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to just change grails version in `application.properties` file and run `grailsw wrapper` to upgrade wrapper. However this doesn't work when upgrading from 2.1.x to 2.2.x anymore.

Comment: Worked from 2.4.4 to 2.4.5

Comment: This does seem to work in later versions of the 2.x branch. Seems 3.x removed the wrapper (and there's debate whether it's coming back).